# Sending/Receiving Next Message to a Web Socket Connection Disrupts Focus for Inline Editing. Angular 9 Material Table

Tags: angular, typescript, websocket, rxjs, angular-material

This isn't exactly an error related question, but more of a question revolving behaviors. This is all in Angular 9 using RxJS and Material mainly. I have a table that is hooked up to a web socket connection. Updates are pushed to the group on blur or change depending on the Column. This all works well and everything gets updated as needed.

I have a specific use-case where I need this table to use collaborative editing, hence why I went with web sockets. And collaborative editing is where the issues arise.

If User 1 is editing Row 1, and User 2 makes a change in the middle of the edit it will destroy User 1's focus and update their Table for them.

GIF: https://gyazo.com/728ebf719df4095ab43ee8c207e4ddfb

At the end of that gif you can see the Select's getting closed on both sides by 1 update.

**GOAL**

I would like for the users to be able to edit simultaneously without their focus on current selections being destroyed. I have a working example in my application that I have for the life of me not been able to replicate.

GIF: https://gyazo.com/d1b2fef99ec8b736e9dbc178f067aac1

Currently I'm using a service to manage the websocket connection across components.

**The socket setup and subscription looks roughly like this:**

```js
connectToWebSocket(selectedDateObject: Date, locationNum: string) {
this.chatSocket = new WebSocketSubject(
      environment.websocketUrl + '/chat/' + WEBSOCKETNAME + '/');
      
// Unfiltered Datasource
this.chatSocket.subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      if (data.message !== null && data.message !== undefined) {
        this.dataSourceSunday.data = data.message.dateMessages.sunday;
        this.dataSourceMonday.data = data.message.dateMessages.monday;
        this.dataSourceTuesday.data = data.message.dateMessages.tuesday;
        this.dataSourceWednesday.data = data.message.dateMessages.wednesday;
        this.dataSourceThursday.data = data.message.dateMessages.thursday;
        this.dataSourceFriday.data = data.message.dateMessages.friday;
        this.dataSourceSaturday.data = data.message.dateMessages.saturday;
      } else {
        this.dataSourceSunday.data = [];
        this.dataSourceMonday.data = [];
        this.dataSourceTuesday.data = [];
        this.dataSourceWednesday.data = [];
        this.dataSourceThursday.data = [];
        this.dataSourceFriday.data = [];
        this.dataSourceSaturday.data = [];
      }
    });
}


updateWebSocket(payload: { message: { dateMessages: { sunday: any; saturday: any; tuesday: any; wednesday: any; thursday: any; friday: any; monday: any } } }) {
    this.chatSocket.next(payload);
  }
```

The websockets are based on a weeks worth of data so they end up getting forked into a dataSource for each day. Then on INIT of the single day's Table the component is pointed to the subscription for that day from the Web Socket service. Is it possible to update the rows around the row being edited and prevent the focus from being destroyed?

Any resources, help, or discussion would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks for taking the time to read this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this.

The solution was to implement the trackBy API. I had no idea this existed and found it on a whim in another stack overflow. It feels like magic, but it works exactly how I want it too.

```html
<table mat-table *ngIf="currentFilterView === 'all'" [dataSource]="webSocketDataSource"
       [trackBy]="trackById"
       multiTemplateDataRows>
       

trackById(index, item) {
  console.log(item._id);
  return item._id;
}
```